# Using Jquery and Ajax to save a file in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, file, save

I have a button that uses jQuery and ajax to call a server side script to create a text file and sends back the following response:

```
Response.ContentType = "csv";
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fName);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(btFile);
Response.End();
```

However, the save dialog does not appear.
If I don't use ajax and perform a full postback with the same code, it works. Any ideas?

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#reportButton').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GenerateReport.aspx",
            data: "id=0",
            success: function(){
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using AJAX (which will not work, as Brian mentions), you can fake it by using jQuery to dynamically create a form and an iframe to post it to. [Here is an example I found](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/) -- you should read through the comments for some improvements (like the use of a dynamically created iframe to prevent problems if your page does not return the proper headers).

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the AJAX, and if the request was made as a standard request outside JQuery, you would get the save dialog box.  JQuery requests would stream the data to the callback...